# Transfer Data Between Lists

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Currently i am working on a project, where data between two lists is getting exchanged. In general if list with same length, we can run a loop to get/set data in the lists.
But in my case, i want to make a certain user interface selection, where user can choose which data(index) of list-1 need to be assigned to list-2.

Currently i am thinking about using FindIndex() function to get the index and then pull data from list-1 to 2 based on index property.

Now incase of list is having 1000 or more length, what will be a good practice to exchange the data considering performance of application?

Comment: Depending on which control is being used, it may be that you can use some entity which contains both the text to be displayed and other information for each list entry. Then it would just be a case of using the other information for the selected item. (Also, it may not be a good user experience to 1000 or more items to look through in one place.)

Comment: For lookups, consider using a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2). They are much faster than lists, if you can lookup an item by key.

Comment: Have you considered a CheckedListBox for this task? If interested I can post a possible solution.

Comment: Check list box can be used for the selection of data which need to be transferred, probably by capturing the selectedindex. But will it be an efficient way to do so?

Comment: In regards to a CheckedListBox, I would not use SelectedIndex.

Comment: See: [CheckedListBox.CheckedItems Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems). And don't add strings to the CheckedListBox but add your objects and make sure the class does override `ToString()` to generate an appropriate display in the list. The CheckedItems property will then yield the objects without having to deal with indexes. Just cast them to your class.

Comment: I will give it a try using CheckedListBox.

Comment: Thanks Olivier, You suggestions does helps. How can a mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to transfer information.
I suggest two methods

1.With linq

```
_listTesta = (from c in _listTesta
              join ct in _listTestB
                         on c.Id equals ct.Id into g
              from ct in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where c.Id != null
              select new Testa
              {
                  Name = ct == null ? c.Name : ct.Name,
                  Family = ct == null ? c.Family : ct.Family,

                  Id = ct == null ? c.Id : ct.Id,
              }).ToArray();
```

example data:

```
List<Testa> _t = new List<Testa>();
List<TestB> _ta = new List<TestB>();

var _listTesta = Enumerable.Range(1000, 50).Select(i => new Testa(i, "n" +
i, "nf" + i)).ToArray();

var _listTestB = Enumerable.Range(1000, 20).Select(i => new TestB(i, "nb" +
i, "fb" + i)).ToArray();
```

2.With an automapper

[Automapper](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-automapper-in-c-sharp)
[automapper-net-core](https://code-maze.com/automapper-net-core/)

Comment: How to does it verify the selection of user?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.do you want Confirm your question. ?https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow